# C# linked lists sort values and insert int in correct place

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a linked list function which sorts the list into non-descending order (e.g. 1,2,6,9) and inserts the integer (5) into the correct place (e.g. 1,2,5,6,9).

So far I have created a temporary list to read from and a new list to write to. However, I haven't been able to successfully place the integer into the correct position.

Program console call code

```
LinkGen<int> link1 = new LinkGen<int>(5);
LinkListGen<int> testList = new LinkListGen<int>();

testList.AddItem(7);
testList.AddItem(6);
testList.AddItem(8);
testList.AddItem(9);
testList.AddItem(16);

testList.InsertInOrder(10);
```

LinkGen class

```
class LinkGen<T>
{
    private T data;
    private LinkGen<T> next;

    public LinkGen(T item)
    {
        data = item;
        next = null;
    }

    public LinkGen(T item, LinkGen<T> list)
    {
        data = item;
        next = list;
    }

    public LinkGen<T> Next
    {
        set { this.next = value; }
        get { return this.next; }
    }

    public T Data
    {
        set { this.data = value; }
        get { return this.data; }
    }
}
```

LinkListGen set up

```
class LinkListGen<T> where T:IComparable
{
    private LinkGen<T> list;

    public LinkListGen()
    {
        list = null;
    }
```

AddItem, AppendItem and InsertInOrder Functions

```
    public void AddItem(T item)
    {
        list = new LinkGen<T>(item, list);
    }

    public void AppendItem(T item)
    {
        LinkGen<T> temp = list;

        if (temp == null)
            list = new LinkGen<T>(item);
        else
        {
            while (temp.Next != null)
            {
                temp = temp.Next;
            }
            temp.Next = new LinkGen<T>(item);
        }
    }

    public void InsertInOrder(T item)
    {
        LinkGen<T> temp = list;
        LinkListGen<T> newList = new LinkListGen<T>();

        if (list == null)
            AddItem(item);
        else
        {
            while (list != null)
            {
                if (item.CompareTo(temp.Data) < 0)
                {
                    newList.AppendItem(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    newList.AppendItem(temp.Data);
                    temp = temp.Next;
                }
            }
            //temp.Next = new LinkGen<T>(item);
        }
    }
```

(apologies about not originally giving enough code, if more is necessary please let me know)

Comment: What is your definition of  `LinkListGen<T>` and `LinkGen<T>`. For the linked list once you find the position to insert into, if it is not the end of the list, you'll need to update the pointer (of the previous and next nodes when they apply) to the node being inserted.

Comment: Without seeing your code for `LinkListGen<T>` or `LinkGen<T>` or even knowing to which class the methods you provided belong, it's just too difficult to know what you've done.  Please provide more of the code.    There's not enough code here for us to reproduce your problem.  From what's here though, I do see obvious problems such as `while (list != null)` where you should have `while (temp != null)`

Comment: Also, there's no need for a "new list".  You just want to find the node that will be the parent of the node that you want to insert.  Once you know that, the "insert a node after this node" operation is straightforward.

Comment: Still missing `AddItem` code

Comment: Thanks Wyck for the response and sorry about not presenting enough code (this is my first time here) I know what the program needs to achieve such as inserting this particular integer before the next node is greater than it. Only translating this into C# syntax is my problem here

Comment: Do you know what recursion is? I think it's much simpler than trying to do it procedurally. This is a common beginner programming problem so you can find here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-sort-a-linked-list-that-is-sorted-alternating-ascending-and-descending-orders/

Answer (score 0):

After entering this `while` loop, when will `list` ever equal `null` again?

```
        while (list != null)
        {
            if (item.CompareTo(temp.Data) < 0)
            {
                newList.AppendItem(item);
                // and then...?
            }
            else
            {
                newList.AppendItem(temp.Data);
                temp = temp.Next;
            }

            // never-ending loop
        }
```

And then you do nothing with locally-scoped `newList`.

Comment: Good point Moho, this function is really a mongrel piece of code consisting of little tidbits from all over the place as I struggled to make it work. It should really be something along the lines of, in pseudo terms, while (list.last() != null).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to find the node that your new node belongs after, then insert it there.  The special case is when the new node goes at the head of the list, in which case you need to update your list head reference which you call `list`.

```
        public void AppendItem(T item)
        {
            if (list == null)
                list = new LinkGen<T>(item);
            else {
                LinkGen<T> temp = list;
                while (temp.Next != null) {
                    temp = temp.Next;
                }
                temp.Next = new LinkGen<T>(item);
            }
        }

        public void InsertInOrder(T item)
        {
            if (list == null || item.CompareTo(list.Data) < 0) {
                list = new LinkGen<T>(item) { Next = list };
            } else {
                LinkGen<T> temp = list;
                while (temp.Next != null && !(item.CompareTo(temp.Next.Data) < 0)) {
                    temp = temp.Next;
                }
                temp.Next = new LinkGen<T>(item) { Next = temp.Next };
            }
        }
```